# How to customise order cart customer information pane

Tags: 7, ubercart

During checkout, I can add fields to billing or delivery information, but how can I add fields to customer information, or create another customized pane for them?

Example:

Student Information:

Name: Skill interest: Phone: Email: etc.....

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [Ubercart Webform Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_webform) module.

This module integrates two other modules: webform and ubercart. It allows you sell products directly from your webforms. It is particularly suited to be used as part of a registration system.

Using this module you can create additional field in check page.

Comment: Thank for your reply Smalution. I had installed this module and enable it. I read how to get it started. Unfortunately, I still not sure where to start. I go check either ubercart or webform nothing change. Need advice.

Comment: there is a option in webform configuration to integrate with uber cart form.

Comment: I can see Product, Product grid, Product list and Hidden is already checked, but it does not appear in the Form components.

Comment: Seem like not working...is there any other alt solution?